# how to check if 2 string have same characters or no? - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want check if 2 string have same characters or no?

like:
"aand" and "daan" => true
"aafw" and "kaaw" => false

this is my code:

```
def procedures(txt1, txt2):
    str1 = txt1.lower()
    str2 = txt2.lower()
    for i in str1:
        for j in str2:
            if i == j:
                str1.replace(i, "", 1)
                str2.replace(i, "", 1)
                print("did")
    if str1 == "" and str2 == "":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

but it returns `False` for `alii` and `liai`!

**what I do?**

Comment: You don't really need two loops, you can solve this in linear time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known problem with many possible solutions.  Try this:

```
def procedures(txt1, txt2):
    return sorted(txt1) == sorted(txt2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a python-string just like you iterate over a list/tuple. A simple function would be:

```py
def stringCompare(a, b):
    for i in a:
        if i not in b:
            return False
        
    return True

print(stringCompare("aand", "daan"))
>> True

print(stringCompare("aafw", "kaaw"))
>> False

print(stringCompare("alii", "liai"))
>> True
```

**Note** the above function only checks if all the characters in both the string are equal or not. Now, for checking the number of occurrences, you can use the `collections` as:

```py
from collections import Counter

def stringCompare2(a, b):
    # also compares the occurance
    occurance_dict_a = Counter(a)
    occurance_dict_b = Counter(b)
    
    return occurance_dict_a == occurance_dict_b

print(stringCompare2("abc", "aabc"))
>> False

print(stringCompare2("abc", "cba"))
>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

Str objects are not editable. So `str.replace` method returns a new string. You must assign to `str1` and `str2` result. So your code now must be like this:

```
def procedures(txt1, txt2):
    str1 = txt1.lower()
    str2 = txt2.lower()
    for i in str1:
        for j in str2:
            if i == j:
                str1 = str1.replace(i, "", 1)
                str2 = str2.replace(j, "", 1)
                print("did")
    if str1 == "" and str2 == "":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Or you can make list of characters from original strings and sort them. So if
the strings have same characters, they will be turned into same character sequences (lists).

```
def procedures(txt1, txt2):
    seq1 = list(txt1.lower())
    seq2 = list(txt2.lower())

    seq1.sort()
    seq2.sort()

    if seq1 == seq2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you take the number of occurences into account ? If so, one could imagine to turn each str into a list of chars, and then to sort each list. It would then remain to compare these lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
def procedures(txt1, txt2):
str1 = txt1.lower()
str2 = txt2.lower()

str1 = list(str1)
result = False

for dt in str1:
    if dt in str2:
        result = True
    else:
        result = False

return result 

print(procedures('neeraj','prakash'))
print(procedures('neeraj','neeraj'))
```

you have to create a list for the first text then check one by one in the second str using the loop. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

first of all we sort both strings. second compare them.

```
def equal(a,b):
    a = sorted(a)
    b = sorted(b)
    if a == b:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: consider this : 
```
def equal(a,b):
    return  sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```